# UIManagedDocument vs NSManagedObject: Performance

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data, ios7, uikit

I'm trying to write a iOS note taking app that is blazingly fast for a large number of notes and that syncs without ever blocking the UI. (Don't worry, it's just a learning project, I know there are a billion note apps for iOS). I have decided to use Core Data (mostly because of the excellent posts by [Brent Simmons](http://inessential.com) about [Vesper](http://vesperapp.co/)). I know UIManagedDocument can do async reads and writes and has a lot of functionality built in, so I'm wondering if there is any information on which would be faster for a fairly simple notes app. I can't really find a lot of information about people using UIManagedDocuments for anything other than a centralized, basically singleton, persistent store. Is it suitable for 1000s of documents? Would it be faster or slower than just a database of NSManagedObjects? It seems like most information I can find about Core Data is oriented towards people using NSManagedObject, so any information about UIManagedDocuments being used in production apps would be really helpful. At this point, the only thing I can think of is to just write the whole app both ways, load 10,000 notes into it, and see what happens.

**Update**
To clarify, I'm not learning iOS development and Objective-C, the "learning project" mostly means that I've never used Core Data and would like to learn how to write a really performant Core Data application.

Comment: Core Data is part of the core framework of iOS. It is as closed source as the rest of the operating system/libraries are and hardly minimally documented.  It is more documented than writing to plist files :)

Answer (score 11):

`UIManagedDocument` is designed/intended for document based applications.  One `UIManagedDocument` instance per document.  If you are not building a document based application then you should **not** be using `UIManagedDocument`.

Everything that people like about `UIManagedDocument` can be accomplished with very little effort using the Core Data stack directly.  `UIManagedDocument` abstracts you away from what your persistence layer is doing.  Something you really do not want.

If you want a high performance Core Data application you do not want to be using `UIManagedDocument`.  You will run into issues with it.  It will do things at random times and cause performance issues.

You are far, far, better off learning the framework properly.

In the case of Vesper, those are not documents; they are too small. Think of documents as Word files, or Excel files. Large complicated data structures that are 100% isolated from each other.

Also, whether you use a `UIManagedDocument` or not, you will be using `NSManagedObject` instances.  `NSManagedObject`, `NSManagedObjectContext`, `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` are all foundational objects in Core Data.  `UIManagedDocument` is just an abstraction layer on top.

Finally, Core Data is not a database.  Thinking of it that way will get you into a jam.  Core Data is an object model that can persist to disk and one of the persistence formats happens to be SQLite.

### Update (Running Into Problems)

`UIManagedDocument` is an abstraction on top of Core Data.  To use `UIManagedDocument` you actually need to learn **more** about Core Data than if you just used the primary Core Data stack.

`UIManagedDocument` uses a parent/child context internally.  Don't understand that yet?  See the point above.  What it also means is that your requests for it to save are "taken under advisement" as opposed to being saved right then and there. This can lead to unexpected results if you don't understand the point of it or don't want it to save when it feels like it.

`UIManagedDocument` uses asynchronous saves and at most you can request that it save. Doesn't mean it is going to save now, nor does it mean you can easily stop and wait for the save to complete.  You need to trust that it will complete it.  In addition, it may decide to save at an inopportune moment.

When you start looking for performance gains with Core Data you tend to want to build the stack in a very specific way to maximize the benefit to your application.  That is application dependent and with the abstracts in `UIManagedDocument` you get limited very quickly.

Even in a situation where I was building a document based application I would **still** not use `UIManagedDocument`.  Just to much behind the curtain.

Comment: Not everyone wants to / can afford to invest the time to learn the frameworks properly on day 1, and some apps don't need the flexibility of pure Core Data. You and I may have invested the time to learn Core Data, and may always write our own custom invocations with it, but Apple had some audience of Devs and Apps in mind when they commissioned these convenience classes. Might some newer devs be more easily hooked by getting a basic application running, and then becoming intrigued enough with the possibilities of Core Data to dig deeper and maybe even buy a book on the subject?...

Comment: Those developers would be best served using the templates that Apple provides which **do not** use a `UIManagedDocument`.  `UIManagedDocument` does things in a very unfriendly way that takes experience to understand. Just the asynchronous opening is extremely difficult to wrap your head around when you are first coming to Core Data. Then factoring in the fact that calling `-save` on its `UIManagedObjectContext` doesn't actually save it to disk and a lot of other fun facts makes it ill-suited for a learning tool.

Comment: I'm with you that in general UIManagedDocument would not be my go to "hello world" of Core Data. OP sounded like a go getter who already understood singletons and synchronicity, and I read (or perhaps misread) his question as "Should I learn Core Data abstractly and attempt to apply it to Docs, or launch into things by patterning off of Apple's invocation of my exact project?" Between those extremes, my advice was to use UIManagedDocument as a springboard. I think we can both encourage OP to invest in the learning curve of Core, GCD and NSOperationQueue regardless. They're worth it.

Comment: @ryancumley if core data is too complicated to learn, then you shouldn't use any solution that is based on core data. Because then you need to learn how that solution works *and still learn how core data works*. Personally I'd just store the notes on a plain text file on disk, with an SQLite file for metadata (or heck, even just a binary plist... those can handle a million or so records with perfectly fast performance, as long as the contents will fit in RAM property lists are screaming fast).

Comment: Thanks @AbhiBeckert! I'm not talking about to learn only one or the other, I'm talking about what to learn FIRST. From the brief paragraph of knowledge we have about OP, he sounds to me like the kind of person who could use UIManagedDocument as a good launch point into Core and GCD etc, not in lieu of it forever. It's the difference between "here's a book on GCD" vs. here's how Apple specifically applied GCD to a problem that you are currently interested in. Neither learning style is more correct, I just gave my opinion to OP on how I'd approach it given what I knew about him.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra I understand it's not a database, but I was attempting to distinguish between a file-based UIDocument strategy. Apparently, though, UIManagedDocument can also use a database as a persistence strategy, but I didn't see that in the documentation until today. Your  description of what is a document is really helpful. If you could expound upon "You will run into issues with it", I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @ryancumley You understood correctly, I really wanted to know if documents were an appropriate abstraction to use for notes. My goal is to learn Core Data, and from what you all are saying, UIManagedDocument is not a good way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is likely to come down to how the rest of your code is implemented, and not necessarily the difference between a UIManagedDocument or a NSManagedObject.

Think of UIManagedDocument as a specific niche implementation of CoreData, that already has the parts of CoreData you want baked into it's structure to save you (the developer) a little bit of time writing code. It's been purpose built for handling UIDocuments, and multi-threading.
Under the hood, it's likely that UIManagedDocument is using CoreData as well as you would (assuming you know what you're doing), but it's theoretically possible you could cut some corners by knowing the exact and inane details of your implementation.

If you're new to CoreData, or GCD and NSOperationQueue, then you'll likely save a ton of developer time by leveraging UIManagedDocument instead of rolling your own.

A very apt analogy would be to using a NSFetchedResultsController to run your UITableView, rather then rolling your own CoreData and UITableView implementation.

If you're new to objective-C, I'd recommend you bang out something functional with UIManagedDocument at first. Later you get lost in the weeds of dispatch_asynch() and NSFetchRequest, and pick up a few milliseconds of performance here and there.

Cheers!

Comment: `UIManagedDocument` is not intended to be used as the application's sole stack.  It is meant to be used in a document based application.  Using it saves you 10 minutes of time at the beginning of the project and costs you numerous hours/days/weeks at the end when you are performance tuning and ripping it back out again.

Comment: Fair point, although I'm not sure where my answer implied that you could use UIManagedDocument as a full stack (can you quote where I give this impression?). I equated it to an NSFetchedResultsController, which is also not a full data stack, but rather a prepackaged tool to cut out some glue code surrounding one particular usage of CoreData. And might I humbly suggest that some developers would spend more than 10 minutes successfully setting up Core and GCD and would gladly use an Apple flavored preset?

Comment: A large majority of developers use Apple's template so it takes them even less time than the ones who write the stack themselves.  My comment about the sole stack is for everyone reading your answer.  A developer is not going to save time using `UIManagedDocument`.

Comment: Thanks, I added an update about what I'm really trying to learn, but if I were new to Objective-C and Cocoa, I might be more interested in UIManagedDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Just store a plain text file on the disk for each note.

Keep a separate database (using sqlite or perhaps just `-[NSDictionary writeToFile:atomically]`) to store metadata, such as the last user modification date and the last server sync date for each note.

Periodically talk to the server, asking it for a list of stuff that has changed since the last time you did a sync, and sending any data on your end that has changed in the same time period.

This should be perfectly fast as long as you have less than a million note files. Do all network and filesystem operations on an NSOperationQueue.